Why is footer not taking 100% width?
I have this simple React app and my footer does not take 100% width (I see small white space on the left and right sides). Can anyone tell me what I'm missing, please?
Here's LIVE DEMO
Here's my css:
.App {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 25px 0;
}




App.tsx
  return (
     <div className="App">
       <Footer />
     </div>
    );



Images of my issue:


Link does not work. "Sandbox not found. It's likely that the Sandbox you're trying to access doesn't exist or you don't have the required permissions to access it."

Please post the JSX as well

Looks like you only have access to that sandbox. I would share the code within the post or create a snippet

@Devmix: It seems that we can't access the demo.  However, this is a good opportunity to start familiarizing yourself with your browser's debugging tools.  If you right-click on your element(s) and inspect them in the browser's DOM explorer, you can use that interface to observe the CSS rules being applied and where they come from.

Ok I updated the LIVE  DEMO link here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-3h2v5n?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx

Does this answer your question?  Removing the default 8px margin from body

The body element has a default 8px margin, have you removed it? If not, you can simply add to you .css file the following code:
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

Hope it helps you, if this is not your case feel free to comment here with more details.
Update: I tried adding it to your codesandbox and it worked here for me.

